# A level 2022 Jan question on percentage increase

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

https://i.postimg.cc/8Pm546SH/Screenshot-20220427-114501-Drive.jpg

https://i.postimg.cc/Z5YqM5Yh/Screenshot-20220427-114552-Drive.jpg

In jan 2022 WBI12/01 they asked

9c. In 1963, there were only three males and 12 females of C. hoodensis left in the wild.
These 15 tortoises were used in a breeding programme.

ii.The wild population of C. hoodensis is now 1800 individuals.
Calculate the percentage increase in the wild population of
C. hoodensis tortoises.
Give your answer to one decimal place.

I did the calculation 1800-15
(new-original value)
Then divided the difference by 15(the original value) times 100 and got 11900.0%
But the mark scheme says

1800-15 = 1785

(1785÷1800)x100% = 99.2%

So I don't understand why they divided by the new value 1800, not the old one 15, since this was a percentage increase calculation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I agree it should be $((1800 - 15)/15) \cdot 100 = 11900\%$ increase in population.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.